# Broken tab completion?

Tags: bash, git

For some reason, 
whenever I want to run a git command and use tab completion to achieve something like :

`$git checkout master`

When I press tab after writing `git check`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, something `hello -n` is being written automatically, so it results in

`$git checkhello -n`

I can't use git CLI with tab completion because of this. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: And other commands work well?

Comment: yes @Matej other commands work well

Comment: And if you write just `git ` and press TAB, does it print all available git commands?

Comment: @Matej no, when pressing tab after git has been typed, it completes with "hello -n" so it becomes " git hello -n "

Comment: Oh, what type of OS do you have?

Comment: @Matej It is weird, isn't it? I'm on Fedora 29.

Comment: Yeah, try `sudo yum install git bash-completion`

Comment: Check whether there is anything in the `.bashrc`, `.profile` or `.bash_profile` files in your home directory that may interfere with auto-completion (for starters, consider grepping all top-level files in $HOME for `hello`). Also, try issuing `set -x` to enable debugging and inspect the output after hitting TAB.

Comment: @VadimLanda Thank you, there was an alias named 'test' with a string "hello" in my .bashrc , I removed it and now tab completion works. Not sure why It'd come up in tab completion though.

Comment: @user607694 `test` is a standard Unix command extensively used in scripts for, well, testing for all kinds of conditions. Bash aliases take precedence over executables of the same name, which means that your alias was called by the auto-completion logic instead of the proper command.

Answer (score 1):

Checked my aliases in .bashrc, one of the alias had the term 'hello' echoed in it. Removing it solved the problem.